# Whats the difference between using JTextField.getText().length() and DocumentFilter for restricting the number of characters in JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtextfield

I want to restrict the user from entering more than 10 characters in the JTextField.
I can do it by checking if(JTextField.getText().length()<10){} which is max number of characters but most of the people have suggested to use a DocumentFilter instead.
Could you explain me the exact reason to do so and what would be the consequences if i go with both.

Answer (score 2):

I think its best to understand how Text Components (which a JTextField is part of) works and what they are made up of.

To cut the long story short I will explain with some extractions from the Java Documentation:

- A Swing Text Component uses a Document to represent its content (This
  content is what you see in the TextComponent).
- Document events occur when the content of a Document changes in any way. You attach a DocumentListener to a text component's Document, rather than to the text component itself. Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html
  for more details
- A DocumentFilter, as the name implies, is a filter for
  the Document mutation methods. When a Document (which you have in
  your JTextField) containing a DocumentFilter is modified it forwards the appropriate method invocation to the DocumentFilter. The default implementation allows the modification to occur. Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html for details.

From the explanation above it is obvious that the following steps are expected to occur when a user interacts with a TextComponent:

1. User interacts with the TextComponent.
2. TextComponent informs it’s underlying Document of the user
   interaction
3. Underlying Document decides what to do with user
   interaction/input. (Underlying Document also allows you decide what to do with user interaction by supplying it a DocumentFilter and/or DocumentListener)
4. After
   Document decides what to do, its current state gets reflected in
   the TextComponent.

From the above explanation, you would agree that it’s best to decide what the TextComponent underlying Document would contain using the Document or an attached DocumentListener.

Now, using JTextField.getText().length, like you want, would mean you want to check the length first and after that ask the TextComponent to go through the process(1-4) above again just to remove the unwanted characters when you could have used it’s Document (or DocumentFilter or a DocumentListener) in the first place.

So to finally answer the question, using both will lead to unexpected results (bugs) and Using the Document (or DocumentFilter or DocumentListener) will be more efficient.

TL;DR What the JTextField displays is gotten from its Document. If you need to tweak what is displayed, it would me more efficient to decide this in the Document before it gets displayed in the JTextField, than using the JTextField to decide what should be displayed right after it is already being displayed.

Comment: so in short, the JTextField is actually controlled by the underlying Document, and thereby also the same Document decides what actions should take place after the JTextField interacts with the user. So the hierarchy is:  Document-------TextComponent